# Ubuntu 14.04 Fullscreen Problem

Tags: 14.04, flash, fullscreen

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my system! The problem is that whenever I put a Flash Player type video full-screen on my second screen, and click away from it on my first screen, it automatically minimises, and it's getting extremely annoying. It really breaks work-flow, and I can't videos shows in full size while working on something else. Help, please!

(Using Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to Google Chrome, there is a hack at https://github.com/ali1234/fullscreenhack that works for PepperFlash. It works by hooking into the system calls that flash uses to get the monitor/geometry info and property changes.

It's pretty simple to use:

First Download the github and extract it (does not matter where). Open a terminal and navigate to the directory.

1. Install dependencies: `sudo apt-get install build-essential libx11-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev`
2. Build it: `make`
3. Run chrome with LD_PRELOAD: `env LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/libfshack-ppapi.so" google-chrome %u`
4. Profit!

That being said, I've used the Maximize Flash extension for chromium and making the browser full screen via F11 with great results, however the Maximize Flash extension has ceased working for me.

Finally the code for step 3 should look something like this:
`env LD_PRELOAD="/home/jan/Downloads/fullscreenhack-master/libfshack-ppapi.so" google-chrome %u`

Answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/362746/315784)